# Allowing others in LAN to access dev sites at personal virtual host (myname.myserver.com)

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I'm on Windows and have used WAMP to set up Apache, MySQL and PHP. I've installed ColdFusion on top of that, and everything works great for my local development. I've also set up my own virtual hosts for all my sites so I can easily switch back and forth between www.mysite.com (production) and michael.mysite.com (dev - virtual host to Apache on my local computer). Works great and I love it.

However, **I want to open things up so that my coworkers (on same LAN) can access my dev site at michael.mysite.com** (and eventually let me access theirs at theirname.mysite.com). I've had this configured for me at a previous employer, but am now the go-to for getting it set up at my new place.

I've already opened up my webroot  in httpd.conf to "Allow from all", and if I give my coworkers my IP that allows them to access my localhost/ from their browser (which is currently the WAMP start page that lists my server config, tools, projects, etc.). But how can I get their computers to recognize all my virtual hosts like michael.mysite.com, michael.myothersite.com, etc? Do I need to configure something on our router?

Thank you. Let me know if I'm not providing enough details about our network.

Comment: You need a mechanism to resolve those names to the correct ip address(es). That mechanism can be DNS or it can be the Hosts file on each user's computer.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done it with windows, but I have 2 devel Ubuntu boxes that do what your looking for.

Basically you'll want your Sys Admins to setup a DNS record to point to your machine's IP address (make sure it's static) and then you'll want to configure apache to answer for that domain.  So for instance (assuming your a windows/active directory setup):

Sys admin will setup: **devel.your.activedirectory.domain.com** points to **192.168.1.50** (whatever that is)

You need to configure apache on your machine to point to the right directory and maybe change the IP address.

That's how I'd do it.